# In Adobe Acrobat I would like to have four radio buttons, each of which will add/replace text into a text field

Tags: javascript, radio-button, adobe, acrobat

In Adobe Acrobat I would like to have four radio buttons, each of which will add/replace text into a text field.  I have the radio buttons and the text field on the form but I don't know what javascript code to use on the buttons to make it work.  For simplicity, button one should enter "one", button two should enter "two", replacing "one" or whatever was there before. Same thing for buttons three and four.

Comment: Have you written any code?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Radio Button Choice for each button to the words you want to appear in the text field then add the following to a custom calculation of the text field.

```
event.value = this.getField("radioButton").value;
```